# Break-down long strings and search/replace individual words

Tags: regular-expression, search

I am trying to do a search and replace in vim (rather, gvim) and keep getting stuck up trying to separate words.

I need to convert something like this:

```
(COND <ASEL&~ASELb|XOR|~XORb> (
```

To this:

```
(COND ASEL=1'b1 && ASELb=1'b0 || XOR=1'b1 || XORb=1'b1 (
```

Basically, every occurrence of these 'words' has to be changed this way:

```
~ABC --> ABC=1'b0
 ABC --> ABC=1'b1
```

I have tried something like this to do it but can't get the pattern to match:

```
s/\([<&|]\)\~\([^<&|]\)\([>&|]\)/\1\2==1'b0\3
s/\([<&|]\)\([^<&|=]+\)\([>&|]\)/\1\2==1'b1\3
```

The idea behind this was to do one 'word' at a time by separating it out in \2 above and then printing \1 and \3 as is with \2=1'b0 or \2=1'b1.

And then take care of the rest, like '&' going to '&&', removing the '<..>' at the ends in the subsequent commands.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this works...

```
(COND <ASEL&~ASELb|XOR|~XORb> (

#step 1
s/\v[<&|]\zs\u+/&=1'b1/g
(COND <ASEL=1'b1&~ASELb|XOR=1'b1|~XORb> (

#step 2
s/\v[<&|]\zs\~(\u+b)/\1=1'b0/g
(COND <ASEL=1'b1&ASELb=1'b0|XOR=1'b1|XORb=1'b0> (

#step 3
s/[&|]/ && /g
(COND <ASEL=1'b1 && ASELb=1'b0 || XOR=1'b1 || XORb=1'b0> (

#step 4
s/[<>]//g
(COND ASEL=1'b1 && ASELb=1'b0 || XOR=1'b1 || XORb=1'b0 (
```

- `\v` is very magic mode so that `()`, `+` etc doesn't need to be escaped
- `\zs` to set start of match

as one-liner

```
s/\v[<&|]\zs\u+/&=1'b1/g | s/\v[<&|]\zs\~(\u+b)/\1=1'b0/g | s/[&|]/ && /g | s/[<>]//g
```